# How to edit the large resolution photo, such as 4200*3200 pixels

Tags: android, image, photo, image-editing

In Android, if you want to edit a large photo of 4200*3200 pixels, you must decode the photo to a bitmap, which can be edited by Canvas or openGLES. But when invoke Bitmap.createBitmap(mBmpWidth,mBmpHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888), the allocation is always so large that getting OOM. How can i resolve it without scale the output photo? Any idea?

Comment: since you didn't provide any code I'wld suggest you use a library like glide or picasso

Comment: @nkoroi25Flow the Gile or Picasso is to show , i want to edit the photo, such as add watermark or filter or other effects, then save to SD card.